# Configuration Issue with Tycho/Maven: "Tycho build extension not configured"

Tags: maven, tycho, maven-extension

I have been following Vogella's tutorial (http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseTycho/article.html) on using Tycho to set up a Maven build environment for my project. My project is already quite big with several plugins, features and an update site, however I managed to get `mvn clean` and `mvn compile` to work fine, and followed the tutorial all the way up to `mvn install`. The issue I am facing now is confusing. I consistently get the following error:

```
[INFO] --- tycho-p2-director-plugin:0.16.0:materialize-products (materialize-products) @ parent ---
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-director-plugin:0.16.0:materialize-products from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-director-plugin:0.16.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@35ce36]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-director-plugin:0.16.0:materialize-products' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) directorRuntime = internal
[DEBUG]   (f) installFeatures = true
[DEBUG]   (f) profile = DefaultProfile
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.micrium.configbuilder:parent:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Documents and Settings\Thomas Sylvester\git\plugin-suite\com.micrium.configbuilder.tycho.master\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@1335332
[DEBUG]   (f) source = targetPlatform
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] No product definitions found. Nothing to do.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] parent ............................................ FAILURE [0.201s]
```

Snipped the list of plugins from this stack trace. They were all skipped. Parent had the failure.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 37.735s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Feb 21 06:42:47 PST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 65M/158M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-director-plugin:0.16.0:materialize-products (materialize-products) on project parent: Execution materialize-products of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-director-plugin:0.16.0:materialize-products failed: Tycho build extension not configured for MavenProject: com.micrium.configbuilder:parent:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Documents and Settings\Erika Redmark\git\plugin-suite\com.micrium.configbuilder.tycho.master\pom.xml -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-director-plugin:0.16.0:materialize-products (materialize-products) on project parent: Execution materialize-products of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-director-plugin:0.16.0:materialize-products failed: Tycho build extension not configured for MavenProject: com.micrium.configbuilder:parent:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Documents and Settings\Erika Redmark\git\plugin-suite\com.micrium.configbuilder.tycho.master\pom.xml
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution materialize-products of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-director-plug
in:0.16.0:materialize-products failed: Tycho build extension not configured for MavenProject: com.micrium.configbuilder:parent:1.1.0-SNAPSHO
T @ C:\Documents and Settings\Erika Redmark\git\plugin-suite\com.micrium.configbuilder.tycho.master\pom.xml
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tycho build extension not configured for MavenProject: com.micrium.configbuilder:parent:1.1.0-SN
APSHOT @ C:\Documents and Settings\Erika Redmark\git\plugin-suite\com.micrium.configbuilder.tycho.master\pom.xml
        at org.eclipse.tycho.core.utils.TychoProjectUtils.getTargetPlatform(TychoProjectUtils.java:63)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.facade.RepositoryReferenceTool.addTargetPlatformRepository(RepositoryReferenceTool.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.facade.RepositoryReferenceTool.getVisibleRepositories(RepositoryReferenceTool.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.plugins.p2.director.DirectorMojo.getTargetPlatformRepositories(DirectorMojo.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.plugins.p2.director.DirectorMojo.getSourceRepositories(DirectorMojo.java:145)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.plugins.p2.director.DirectorMojo.execute(DirectorMojo.java:93)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        ... 20 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

I see that the root of the cause is that the Target Platform is somehow undefined. But when I look up Target Platform on the Eclipse wiki (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform)  it states:

> In order allow Tycho to resolve the project dependencies against
>   anything from a specific p2 repository, add that repository in the
>    section of the POM... In terms of the target platform,
>   this means that the entire content of the p2 repositories specified in
>   this way become part of the target platform.

I have that section in my POM. In fact, here is the full content of my parent POM (defined in a seperate general project as per the tutorial). I omitted only the declaration of all my modules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.micrium.configbuilder</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        ... bunch of modules ...
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <tycho-version>0.16.0</tycho-version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>helios</id>
            <layout>p2</layout>
            <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.16.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-p2-director-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.16.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>materialize-products</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>materialize-products</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>archive-products</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>archive-products</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

Have I missed something? I seemed to have defined what the documentation addresses as the target platform. Am I even seeing the right issue?

Comment: Erika, I would appreciate if you could remove the `resolver=p2` configuration from your examples. This parameter does not exist for the `tycho-maven-plugin` and the `tycho-p2-director-plugin` (and for the not mentioned `target-platform-configuration` plugin, `p2` has been the default value for ages).

Comment: I removed them from my code as well as the example. I had recently added them trying to fix the problem, but as I see now they were irrelevant. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the tutorial.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to execute the `tycho-p2-director-plugin` in your parent POM. This won't work – the plug-in can only be executed in modules with `eclipse-repository` packaging type. Moving the configuration `tycho-p2-director-plugin` configuration into your `eclipse-repository` module(s) will solve the problem described here.

Unfortunately, Tycho doesn't give a good error message in this case. It states "Tycho build extension not configured", but in fact it is configured but is just not executed for the packaging type `pom`.

Comment: Sweet, it seems to be working now. Every module was a success. Thank you very much.